# Global database on Android

Tags: android, database

I don't have a server. I want to host a simple small database globally and free. Is there any site that provides that service?

If so, and if I successfully uploaded my database, has anyone tried to add and get entries to and from a global database in android?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

don't host, include your database with your application instead. when you make changes, release a new version of the application. google app store will take care of distribution very globally and free.

Comment: Thanks. But in my app, changes happen all the time!

Comment: do your users really care about these changes? will they survive using last week's data? last month's data? last year's?

Comment: Actually, I want to send a file from a device to another. I want the first device to upload the file, and save the name + url of the file in the database, such that the second device can download the file. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: with these new requirements, i'm afraid simple file hosting is out of the question, because you most probably will need some kind of software running on the server, authorizing users, receiving uploads, storing files and updating and serving the database. Google AppEngine is free within the limits, but you have to learn python, or you may prefer cheap LAMP hostings that start from $5/month and let you program things in PHP.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot for information. So, that is not a simple issue, not a day or two days of work, isn't it?

Comment: if you want to create a simple web site for your personal testing needs, it basically takes a day or two. but design and implementation of the fully tested and reliable application that can serve thousands and millions of users might take considerably longer.